# cell.textLabel.text not working after update to Xcode 6.2 using swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uilabel

I'm trying to set the value of the cell to a text value of a label that I place in the Main.storyboard, however after updating to Xcode 6.2 it start giving me an error that "UILabel doesn't have a member named text" before the update everything was working fine.

this is the code that I have

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.personajes.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel.text = self.personajes[indexPath.row]
    return cell
```

Comment: You should consider using `dequeueReusableCell` instead of initializing a new cell every time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a ? after textLabel; Xcode expects an Optional here.  Not sure what in the update would have changed that, but if I take the ? out of my similar code thats same error I see.  I believe that Xcode automatically suggested the ? in the previous version.